# Utilizar variáveis na Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, variáveis

Bom, eu tenho a seguinte função na minha Model :

```
public function get_learning_category_list() {
     $categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
        ->from('learning_category t1')
        ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
        ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
        ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
        ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('t1.id')
        ->get()->result_array();
    foreach($categorias as $c){
        $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
        ->from('learning')
        ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
        ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

        $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
        $tt = $c['title'];
        $url = $c['url'];
        if($this->language != 'pt_br'){
            $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
            $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
        }

        $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);

    }

    return $return; //$categorias;
}
```

Dando um `print_r($this->learn->get_learning_category_list());` me resulta neste valor :

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados [id] => 2 [total] => 6 [title_pt_br] => )`

Beleza? Porém eu preciso utilizar (na Model mesmo) estes valores, url title e etc. Como posso fazer isso?

Sendo mais especifico, eu preciso utilizar aqui :

`$category_format = (Aqui url title, ou seja : Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados ).'-cmdo-'.(Aqui o id, ou seja :2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei utilizando:

```
 $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    foreach($categorias as $cat){
        $cat = (object) $cat;
 if($cat->title != '') {
            $return = strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
        }else{
            $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
        }   
    return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

caso seu return esteja retornando os valores da função você pode utilizar a mesma dentro da view e dar um print_r para ver quais valores são retornados dentro da view, caso contrário crie um variável para armazenar o retorno da função e carregue a view passando a mesma `$this->load->view('nome_view', $dados_funcao)`

Comment: Acho que você não compreendeu minha pergunta, acrescentei algumas coisas a pergunta, mostrando onde preciso utilizar estes valores.

Comment: tente usar `get()->row();` no lugar de `get()->result_array();`

Answer (score 0):

Não está claro para mim qual o objetivo de armazenar o retorno dessa função de volta no seu Model.

Porém você pode fazer isso criando uma propriedade na classe do seu Model para armazenar os dados que você vai utilizar.

```
<?php

class Meu_Model {

    protected $learning_category_list;

    // ...

    public function get_learning_category_list() {

         // ...

        $this->learning_category_list = $return;            

        return $return;
    }
}
```

Assim após executar `$this->learn->get_learning_category_list()`, dentro da sua classe você poderá utilizar `$this->learning_category_list`.

Novamente, se você informar com mais detalhes o por que você quer fazer isso dessa forma fique mais claro sugerir uma solução melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu quero definir o formato da url utilizando estes valores, assim : `$category_format = (Aqui url title, ou seja : Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados ).'-cmdo-'.(Aqui o id, ou seja :2);` Entendeu ?

Comment: @GWER continua confuso para mim o por que disso precisa estar dentro do seu Model.

Comment: Assim, eu estou criando uma verificação para ver se o formato da url está correto,  e se ele não estiver, eu redireciono para o url correto. Esta verificação está na minha Controller, ok? 
`if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category()) {
            redirect($this->learn->url_format_category(),'location','301');
            exit;`. Na model eu só preciso definir o formato CORRETO desta url. Fui claro?

Comment: @GWER com seu comentário ficou mais claro o que você quer fazer. [Edite sua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/57120/edit) explicando melhor o que você deseja fazer, pois a pergunta continua sem sentido (o título por exemplo).